# How to identify different action for different location in an ImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

I have an map Image which have some states,  now scenario is that if I will  click any particular state It will be show that state name as an pop up View.

My Problem is that how to identify different actions when I am tapping different state location in map image.

Answer (score 1):

Put a UIButton with the name of the state overlaid ontop of a map.

When users tap on the state name, you will know which state they tapped on.

Or do you not want to show the name of the state on a map?

You could break the state into separate PNG image and carefully place them to make the map look seamless. Assign the image to UIButtons.

Same idea.

Comment: yes this logic was hit on my mind. But there are too many states. It is not a good idea create 100 to 200 button

Comment: I see, then you need a more robust solution. I got an idea. Perhaps you can define a "center point" in X,Y screen coordinate for each state (assuming your map isn't zoomable), then get the user's tapped location and compare the tapped location to each element in array of state center points to see which one is the shortest distance. Then you'll know which state was tapped. See raki's answer for how to get tapped location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add tap gesture recogniser to your image view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapOnMap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showStatePopUp:)]; 
tapOnMap.delegate = self;
[yourMapImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapOnMap];
```

and in the method showStatePopUp:

```
-(void) showStatePopUp:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView: yourMapImageView];
    NSLog(@"tapped location x:%f, y:%f",point.x,point.y);
}
```

Now, you have the location points. Next, handle different actions based on these points.

Comment: I thinks for this i have to made 100 to 200 condition :(

Comment: other wise how you get 100 to 200 states info popup?......if you want to made this simply better to use maps